# Image resize not working in FireFox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have an 1080p image which I included in my code. The code works fine on Chrome, however there are issues on Firefox. In firefox image height is not working, which eventually makes the picture to take the whole screen.

I tried different solutions but couldn't solve this problem. I might have missed a few solutions.

Here is the code:

```
#container{
    width:auto;
    height:60%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;

}


#titleImage{

        max-width:100%;
        max-height:90%;
        width:100%;
}


<body>

   <div id="container">
        <img id="titleImage" src="throne.jpg" />
    </div>
```

I am trying to achieve similar height for the image on all browsers like this [site](http://www.adamgubman.com/).

Regards

Comment: Please can u give us example in jsfiddle or on your server?

Comment: Site you provided is using [CSS Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

Comment: how does the height not work? Does the image get his original height back? I cant reproduce your problem. It works in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m6VBz/1/

Comment: yep the image reproduces its height on firefox. however it works fine on chrome

Answer (score 1):

The image is different in Firefox because you set the height to a percentage. Different browsers will have a different browser height even in full screen due to the GUI around the page you are viewing (this is the graphical user interface that shows you the URL bar/favorites/etc.

You really shouldn't set the height as a percentage.  Try instead something like this

```
#container{
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

adjust the width to what you desire.  Using the JSFiddle Chanckjh created it would be at 70%.  As you can see in the updated JSFiddle the problem is fixed between browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/m6VBz/19/

Hope this helped!